# Функция JSON.stringify

Tags: url, json, javascript

Такой вопрос: когда функция JSON.stringify преобразует данные в JSON, спец. символы, типа +, ?, & и подобные экранируются, или нужно все равно перед передачей в функцию, каждое значение пропустить через encodeURIComponent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вам надо соблюсти только требования JSON, фукнция все сделает за вас. Если какие-то свои дополнительные требования хотите наложить, то нужно прогонять через соответствующие функции.

Вообще гляньте сайт: http://phpjs.org/functions/

Там есть много интересного, в том числе и аналог php функции `json_encode`: http://phpjs.org/functions/json_encode/

Comment: А чем JSON.stringify отличается от аналога json_encode?
Обе же кодируют в формат JSON.

Comment: Ничем. В коде той функции вызывается JSON.stringify, если такая существует, а если нет, то код выполняется дальше. Т.е. по идее будет совместимость со всеми браузерами.